# Why would my home page be the only page to throw a 404 error when form posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an input in my header for a user to submit their zip code. When they submit, a function is run to pull the information of the closest dealer. All other pages just reload normally except the home page. What would be causing this?

Edit:

Here is my code

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="zipcode__search">
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="">
</form>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?reset-zip=true">Enter another zip code</a>
```

The PHP:

```
session_start();
$coordinates = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($_SESSION['zip']).'&sensor=false');
$coordinates2 = json_decode($coordinates);
$user_lat = $coordinates2->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$user_lon = $coordinates2->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    return $miles;
}

$args = array('post_type' => 'dealer', 'order' => 'ASC');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );  
if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    $array = array();
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $dealer_lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_lat', true);
        $dealer_lon = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_lon', true);
        $theid = get_the_ID();

        $distancebetweeneach = distance($user_lat, $user_lon, $dealer_lat, $dealer_lon, "M");
        if(is_nan($distancebetweeneach)):
            $distancebetweeneach = "0";
        endif;
        $array[] = array(
            "distancebetweeneach" => $distancebetweeneach,
            "theid" => $theid
        );
    endwhile; wp_reset_query(); 
endif; 

sort($array); 
$closestdealer = $array[0]['theid'];
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'dealer','orderby' => 'post__in','post__in' => array($closestdealer)); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $closest_dealer_name = get_the_title();
        $closest_dealer_description = get_the_content();
        $closest_dealer_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_address', true);
        $closest_dealer_city = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_city', true);
        $closest_dealer_state = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_state', true);
        $closest_dealer_zip = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_zip', true);
        $closest_dealer_latitude = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_lat', true);
        $closest_dealer_longitude = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dealer_lon', true);
        $closest_dealer_phone= get_field('dealer_phone');
        $closest_dealer_fax = get_field('dealer_fax');
        $closest_dealer_email = get_field('dealer_email');
        $closest_dealer_website = get_field('dealer_website');
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: *"What would be causing this?"* - No code = no idea; could be anything from server error to coder error. From htaccess to code.

Comment: I edited my post with my actual code. Sorry I don't respond quickly.

Comment: `$_GET['reset-zip']` the origin of that is unknown. Plus, `== 'true'` that is checking for a string equaling to "true". If you're looking for a boolean, then you need to remove the quotes from it.

Comment: and make sure you started the session using `session_start();` inside all files using session. Your 404 error may stem from an (syntax) error somewhere.

Comment: I saw your edit `$_GET['reset-zip']` and you're using `?reset-zip=true` which is a boolean not a string. So do `if($_GET['reset-zip'] == true):` and it may work. You should also add `exit;` right after the header.

Comment: See if anything comes from using PHP's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - this could also be an `.htaccess` issue with a rewrite. If this is a "Wordpress" problem, I won't be able to help any further, sorry.

Comment: error reporting shows no errors, and I completely cleared the htaccess file and still having the same issue. I guess its a "Wordpress" problem. Thanks for your help!